# on my Windows Service, I am recieving an error proccesed out System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, windows-services

This service works fine when testing out in Visual Studio locally. But when its time to run it on the server I get the error proccesed out System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly. Is there a way to add a class library to a service? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well what libraries does it use? Have you add references to them? Do they exist in the server?

Comment: compare your local release directory and dlls if all present on the deployed machine also check for GAC if any dlls you are referencing is missing on target

Comment: Where would I put dlls for a service? I added references to the Service in VS 2012, the EXE that I am installing on the server is in the same folder (when testing), but if that is the problem, how do you reference a dll on a service

Comment: Perhaps the dependency assembly is deployed in the GAC on the development machine. You need to do the same on the server. Or, add a local reference to it on the development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider using Process Monitor, a free tool provided by Microsoft. Monitor file activity and it will show you which DLLs it is trying to load from disk. This will tell you which DLLs it can't find.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Will this work with managed assemblies? AFAIK it only works with native libraries.

Comment: I know exactly the DLL I want to load, but how do I load it is the billion dollar question. Locally its fine in visual studio. I take that EXE that it gives me and run a sc create on my server. It installs and I start the service then I get the FileNotFoundException. how did I get it to find that file?